# NetBeans Java OpenGL Library not being found

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to setup Java OpenGL in NetBeans. I have the library imported, and the ones that I'm trying to include in the file are located at:

HelloWorldJOGL > Libraries > JOGL - jogl-java-src.zip > javax.media.opengl >

All of the libraries being included are there (I can search through them and open them in the project tree in NetBeans), but NetBeans is saying it can't find it. I'm not sure how to tell it specifically to look in the Libraries folder, which seems redundant to me, anyway.

The program files are located at:

HelloWorldJOGL > Source Packages > helloworldjogl > HelloWorldJOGL.class

HelloWorldJOGL > Source Packages > helloworldjogl > HelloWorldJOGL.java

I'm not sure how to let it know the libraries are included, like I included them. Again, to me it seems like it's being really stupid, but I really would like to solve it.

The specific error is called, "package javax.media.opengl does not exist."

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy, just go to projects Tab and then in your project right click on Libraries and click on either Add Library or you can click on Add JAR/Folder.
I think this will resolve your problem.

Comment: What I had done earlier is right-clicked on the project, went to preferences, then libraries, clicked "add library," created a new library with the files in the JOGL library, then clicked add and everything showed up. I tried that way just now, too, and it still doesn't think the packages exist.

Comment: Interestingly, I just noticed, is the library tree looks very different if I import it this way. In this version, I can't specifically find the library files I'm looking for. It's just using the other method I mentioned above that produces results that make it easy to find the libraries that the program is looking for.

Comment: have you tried adding the whole folder, and donot forget to import them in your classes

Comment: What do you mean, "import them in your classes?" Currently in my .java, they're all being imported, but it says it doesn't exist for importing. Originally, I tried adding the whole folder. I went back and tried adding just the folder with the specific libraries, unzipped, and it still doesn't know they exist!

Comment: I meant this only that you should import them in your .java files, then I really don't know, whats the problem

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure. There was a class file (I'm using a HelloWorld tutorial file for setting up everything) and I wasn't sure what it was for. All of the libraries are included in the only .java file in the program.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans allow us to install plugins, these can be really helpful some time,
like here for using OpenGL [here](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3260/netbeans-opengl-pack) is a plugin for it.
And if you want to know how to install plugins, it's very simple,
Steps for installing plugin,

1. Goto 'Tools' menu tab
2. click on 'Plugins'
3. Goto 'Downloaded' Tab
4. Click on 'Add Plugins'
5. Browse for the actual jar file of the plugin, or select all NBM files from the zip file you downloaded
6. Click on 'Install'

Comment: Alright, I did that and when I clicked install, it told me this: `The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 1.29.2.8.2 (release version 1) but only 3.33.3.21.40 (of release version different from 1) was found. 

The following plugin is affected:
GLSL editor`

This error sounds like a mistake (it's looking for version newer than 1.29.2.8.2 yet all it found was 3.33.3.21.40??

Comment: I just found this tutorial: http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-getting-started-jogl It said to not install GLSL Editor, so now it's installing. I'll see in a second. You might want to edit the steps.

Comment: Alright. It installed an everything restarted. It gave me a message saying some modules couldn't update. Now I'm back at the project and it still says the same thing. I also checked the Sample folder and there are no OpenGL samples anywhere. :( This is saddening

Comment: Sorry But now I cannot help you anymore

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. It's a strange problem and I'll be looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract the zip archive into a `folder!` If that doesn't work then you may need the `natives` for your OS.

Comment: So, you're saying I have to extract every folder that's in the Java OpenGL Library set? The reason I'm asking is because NetBeans does recognize the specific libraries in the file tree. I can even open the library files in NetBeans.